# sapply with function using multiple columns as input

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data frame with let's say 2 columns and 4 rows (it's bigger... I am just making it simpler) like this: 
Value: 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8
R: 1, 0, 1, 0

I m trying to write a sapply line that given the value of R returns Value when R is 0 and NA when R is 1. 
I would write something like that:

`sapply(dataframe[[R]], function(x) ifelse(x==1,NA,dataframe[[Value]][[indexOf(x)]]))`

Is there something like my "indexOf" (imaginary function) function that i could use?

The task would be very easy using for loops but I want to do it efficiently with sapply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifelse` is what you're looking for.

```
> df = data.frame(Value=c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8),
                  R=c(1, 0, 1, 0))

> df$New = ifelse(df$R==1, df$Value, NA)

> df
  Value R New
1   0.2 1 0.2
2   0.3 0  NA
3   0.5 1 0.5
4   0.8 0 NA
```

Comment: In fact, I've done the opposite of what you asked, if you wanted to insert `NA` where `R` does `==1`, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sapply` or `ifelse` for this task. You can use mathematical operators.

```
dat <- data.frame(Value = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8),
                  R = c(1, 0, 1, 0))

transform(dat, NewCol = Value * NA ^ R)
#   Value R NewCol
# 1   0.2 1     NA
# 2   0.3 0    0.3
# 3   0.5 1     NA
# 4   0.8 0    0.8
```